# loading the json object values in a column using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table and I need to put the json object values in a column but not in rows. Something like this

```
Name       AAA
Address    BBB
Zip        CCC
```

I have attached the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rrzZU/852/

Answer (score 3):

You can simply create the `<th>` tags inside the loop.

But I highly recommend to use a template engine like [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/)

```js
var response = [{
      "name":"aaa",
      "address":"bbb",
      "zip":"ccc"
     }];

$(function() {
    $.each(response, function(i, item) {
        var tr ="<tr>";
        tr+= "<th>Name :<th>"
        tr+= "<td id='name'>" + item.name + "</td>";
        tr+= "</tr><tr>";
        tr+= "<th>Address :<th>"
        tr += "<td id='address'>" + item.address+ "</td>";
        tr += "</tr><tr>"
        tr+= "<th>Zip :<th>"
        tr += "<td id='zip'>" + item.zip + "</td>";
        
        tr += "</tr>";
        $("#report tbody").append(tr);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="report"  >
<tbody>
 
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: But I want it to be outside the loop because I don't want the whole table to be loaded after the AJAX call..

Comment: I can't say it's impossible but I HIGHLY recommend you to use a template engine like mustache or handlebars in order to get what you want asap and also more easily. But if you insist for doing it in this way, it's a bit tricky :D

Comment: I will take a look into it.. thanks..!!